# printing the solution of towers of Hanoi

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a piece of code to solve the towers of Hanoi problem recursively:

```
def printMove(fr, to):
print('Move from tower ' + str(fr) + ' to tower ' + str(to))

def Towers(n, fr, to, spare):
    if n == 1:
        printMove(fr, to)    
    else:
        Towers(n-1, fr, spare, to)
        Towers(1, fr, to, spare)
        Towers(n-1, spare, to, fr)

n=int(raw_input('Enter the initial number of disks: '))
fr=str(raw_input('Enter the number for the initial tower: '))
to=str(raw_input('Enter the number for the second tower: '))
spare=str(raw_input('Enter the number for the third tower: '))
print(Towers(n,fr,to,spare))
```

It works properly but after it prints all the movements, it prints also 'None' and I don't know why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of `print(Towers(n,fr,to,spare))` do `Towers(n,fr,to,spare)`.

None is printed because `Towers` isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, every function returns something. If you don't explicitly `return` anything, your function returns `None` by default.

In your code, the return value of `Towers` is `None`, so when you pass it into your `print` statement, you end up printing `None`.